# add kartik into yii 2

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

i'm a new yii 2 developer .
i want to add kartik libary into my site and use the gridview !
i install the kartik and when i write use kar it autocomplete  kar to kartik and this show that the libary installed .
but when i use an empty gridview like this :

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;
/*

CODE

*/
        <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ]
]); ?>
```

it says

> Class 'kartik\grid\GridView' not found

i use basic version of yii 2 in php storm !
what should i do for fix this problem ?

Comment: is it in your /vendor folder?

Comment: @vher2 yes , in vendor file i have this : kartik-v and in that i have yii2-grid and yii2-krajee-base files

Comment: @ali What happens on cntrl+click in GridView

Comment: @KiranMuralee what do you mean about crt+click in GridView ???

Comment: what he means, pressing ctrl+click on GridView brings you to GridView class.

Comment: how did you install kartik library?

Comment: @ali click on the GridView .Press ctrl on keyboard and then again click on it.I use netbeans and when I do this it will load the class file into the editor if one is there.

Comment: how did you install kartik? i mean did you install it through composer? or download it and copy it to vendor folder?

Comment: sorry i was click on grid !!! i try to click on katrick but it's not get work !!! @KiranMuralee

Comment: @vher2 i install via composer

Comment: @ali what is the namespace value

Comment: in `use kartik\grid\GridView;` when i click on grid it show me the right libary : `namespace kartik\grid;` but katrik has no reaction by clicking !!!

Comment: @KiranMuralee what do you mean about namespace value ? i'm sorry i'm not really good at Yii2 :)))

Comment: After installation, did you add the gridview into your configuration file? See http://demos.krajee.com/grid#module

Answer (score 0):

```
use kartik\grid\GridView as kGridView;

<?= kGridView::widget($gridView); ?>
```

Comment: standard YII2 GridView::class may conflict with same na,e from kartik.
in may case i try use both...

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to check for solution:**

**1** Check, in which project folder your are.

**2** In composer.json file, check require section for the line `"kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev"`

**3** If it's not present Install karthik gridview by your preferred way.